# What SSL cipher suite has the least overhead?

Tags: performance, security, ssl, cryptography

What [SSL cipher suite](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#SSL_v3_0_cipher_suites_) has the least overhead?   A clearly compromised suite would be undesirable,  however there age degrees of problems.   For instance RC4 is still in the SSL 3.0 specification.  What is a good recommendation for a highly traffic website?  Would the cipher suite change if it wasn't being used for http?

Comment: If this is not a generic question you should check your servers if the used CPUs already include cryptographic extensions for speeding up symmetric crypto operations (e.g. AES). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set  Additionally your software has be compiled so that it uses such features.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends if you talk about network or CPU overhead.

Network overhead is about packet size. The initial handshake implies some asymmetric cryptography; the DHE cipher suites (when the server certificates is used for digital signatures only) imply a `ServerKeyExchange` message which will need a few hundred extra bytes compared with a RSA key exchange. This is a one-time cost, and clients will reuse sessions (continuing a previous TLS session with a symmetric-only shortened key exchange).

Also, data is exchanged by "records". A record can embed up to 16 kB worth of data. A record has a size overhead which ranges from 21 bytes (with RC4 and MD5) to 57 bytes (with a 16-byte block cipher such as AES, and SHA-1, and TLS 1.1 or later). So that's at worst 0.34% size overhead.

CPU overhead of SSL is now quite small. Use `openssl speed` to get some raw figures; on my PC (a 2.4 GHz Core2 from two years ago), RC4 appears to be about twice faster than AES, but AES is already at 160 MBytes/s, i.e. 16 times faster than 100baseT ethernet can transmit. The integrity check (with MD5 or SHA-1) will be quite faster than the encryption. So the cipher suite with the least CPU overhead should be `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5`, but it will need some rather special kind of setup to actually notice the difference with, e.g., `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`. Also, on some of the newer Intel processors, there are [AES-specific instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set), which will make AES faster than RC4 on those systems (the VIA C7 x86 clones also have some hardware acceleration for some cryptographic algorithms). RC4 may give you an extra edge in some corner cases due to its very small code -- in case your application is rather heavy on code size and you run into L1 cache issues.

(As usual, for performance issues, actual measures *always* beat theory.)

Comment: Although not defined by the cipher suite, it is also worth adding that the size of your RSA key materially affects the CPU overhead of setting up a new session.

Answer (score 4):

The ciphersuite with the less overhead is RSA_WITH_RC4_MD5. Note that the way RC4 is used in TLS does not render it broken, as for example in WEP, but still its security can be questioned. It also uses the HMAC-MD5, which also is not the best choice, even though there no attacks known yet. Several web sites (unfortunately) only use that ciphersuite for efficiency. If you use an intel server with AES-NI instructions you might want to experiment with RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA1. It is faster than RSA_WITH_RC4_MD5 in the systems I've tested.

Comment: It tells all of that here too http://zombe.es/post/4078724716/openssl-cipher-selection

Answer (score 2):

I was searching about SSL/TLS and bumped into this one. I know the thread is old and just wanted to add a few updates just in case someone gets lost here.

Some ciphers offer more security and some more performance. But since this was posted, several changes to SSL/TLS, most specially on security has been introduced.

For **good and always updated ciphers** check out [this SSL/TLS generator by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS)

It is also worth to note that if you are concern with performance, there are other aspects in the SSL connection that you could explore such as:

1. OCSP stapling
2. Session resumption (tickets)
3. Session resumption (caching)
4. False Start (NPN needed)
5. HTTP/2